# How do I redirect a user to a custom 404 page in ASP.NET MVC instead of throwing an exception?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, exception, routes

I want to be able to capture the exception that is thrown when a user requests a non-existent controller and re-direct it to a 404 page. How can I do this?

For example, the user requests `http://www.nosite.com/paeges/1` (*should be* `/pages/`). How do I make it so they get re-directed to the 404 rather than the exception screen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at [this page](http://richarddingwall.name/2008/08/09/three-common-aspnet-mvc-url-routing-issues/) for routing your 404-errors to a specified page.

Comment: You might want to update the answer to include relevant details in it.

Answer (score 16):

Just use a route:

```
// We couldn't find a route to handle the request.  Show the 404 page.
routes.MapRoute("Error", "{*url}",
    new { controller = "Error", action = "404" }
);
```

Since this will be a global handler, put it all the way at the bottom under the Default route.

Comment: Is this right? Because sure if I define a route for {controller}/{action}/{id} lets say, and the user enters the url with a controller that doesn't exist then it will yellow-screen as that first route will match and your catch all will never be reached?

Comment: I just tried this, and still get the default yellow-screen 404.

Comment: This does work, but it means that you have to have manual routes for all of your controllers, ie no `{controller}/{action}/{id}` instead you'd have to do `Home/{action}/{id}`, `Account/{action}/{id}`, etc

Comment: @SerjSagan, nowadays, you can use route constraints, like:             `routes.MapRoute(
               name: "Home",
               url: "{action}",
               defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" },
               constraints: new { action = "Index|Help|Orders" }
            );`

Answer (score 1):

Found this on the same site - [Strategies for Resource based 404s](http://richarddingwall.name/2008/08/17/strategies-for-resource-based-404-errors-in-aspnet-mvc/)

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged on SO.