# How do I set up a universal controller in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing, maproute

I know it's not perhaps in the true spirit of MVC, but I just want to have a single global controller that always gets called no matter *what* the url looks like. For example, it could be:

http://myserver.com/anything/at/all/here.fun?happy=yes&sad=no#yippie

...and I want that to be passed to my single controller. I intend to obtain the path programmatically and handle it myself--so in other words, I don't really want any routing at all.

I've opened up the global.asax file and found where routes are registered, but I just don't know what to put for the 'url' parameter in MapRoute:

```
routes.MapRoute( "Global", "", new { controller = "Global", action = "Index" } );
```

This (with the blank 'url') works fine for the default path of '/', but if I change it to anything I get a file not found, when I want it to handle *any* url. I also tried "*", etc. but that didn't work.

I couldn't find any definitive reference to the format that the url parameter takes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
routes.MapRoute("Global", "{*url}", new { controller = "Global", action = "Index" } );
```

from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19941/aspnet-mvc-catch-exception-when-non-existant-controller-is-requested) question

Comment: That did it, though I don't understand why. Reading up on those 404 pages now... thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have not removed the default have you?  You need to keep that one.  Maybe try:

```
routes.MapRoute("Global", "/", new { controller = "Global", action = "Index" });
```

Comment: No luck, url routes can't start with a slash.