# ASP.NET MVC handling folder access bad URLs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I am getting these exceptions in my mvc application only on production server through elmah which i don't have any idea how to resolve please help.

System.Web.HttpException: The controller for path '/SupplierPortal/bootstrap/js/non-existent-426306266' was not found or does not implement IController.

System.Web.HttpException: A public action method 'non-existent-762606233' was not found on controller 'AcroSupplierPortal.Controllers.ProfileController'.

Comment: What do you mean by "through elmah"? On a high level the errors seem to be caused by your/external application calling into non-existing controller and/or action methods of your MVC application. You need to cross-check at what point of time such errors are recurring and it would be helpful if you can share those details.

Comment: If you observe the url: `'/SupplierPortal/bootstrap/js/non-existent-426306266` you can see that the request looks to be a `js` script content statically. Does your web application configuration allow that?

Comment: thanks siva gopal for your comment. I am using elmah for exception handling. this request always comes from js or scripts folder. i just want to know if this exception arises from the application or just someone tries to enter this in the url manually.

Comment: And [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122021/stop-exception-from-being-thrown-for-non-existent-controller) points to a way you can consider.

Comment: i have places all my js in BundleConfig file is this something related to this.

Comment: Search the text in whole project to find where is it, may be need ~ before it

Comment: Already done searching there is nothing like such.

Comment: Thanks Siva Gopal..this works..I dont know the reasons but excluding those exceptions from ELMAH works.. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/deploying-web-site-projects/logging-error-details-with-elmah-vb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know the reasons but excluding those exceptions from ELMAH works.. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/deploying-web-site-projects/logging-error-details-with-elmah-vb