# How to redirect current route to the another route when the call have method attribute incorrect web api c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, routes

**Controller**

```
[Route("OrderFood")]
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult OrderFood(Food foodinfo)
{
    //do something
    ...
}

[Route("ResolverError")]
public void ResolverError()
{
    //Return error in a frienly and logging detail about the caller in App Insights
    ...
}
```

**App_Start/RouteConfig**

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "Api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Hello, context is as follows:
My system have some calls to method `OrderFood` by Postman, cause mistake so they call it with method GET. Of course, the call failed and response code **405**.

So, my idea is if user request to `OrderFood` with method **GET**, i will detect it and redirect to route `ResolverError`. At here, i can manage exception and logging detail about the caller.

How about your idea? Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I redirect a user to a custom 404 page in ASP.NET MVC instead of throwing an exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19941/how-do-i-redirect-a-user-to-a-custom-404-page-in-asp-net-mvc-instead-of-throwing)

Comment: Just changing the text in routedata to OrderFood should work i think. Asp will understand that GET route goes to the lower one and post to top one even if both have the same routedata

Comment: Hello @GSerg 
That answer don't resolve my issue

Comment: I had a route default is Home, i need a another specific route to resolve error!

Comment: Which framework are you using? .NET core or .NET framework?

Comment: Hello, present i using .NET framework, web api v2

Comment: @TrietPham Check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **Global.asax** which is used for higher-level application events such as Application_Start, Session_Start, etc. In that file, we have an event called **Application_PostRequestHandlerExecute** which is fired when the framework has finished executing an event handler. You can use this event for your use case. Try the following code:

```
 protected void Application_PostRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
        if (response.StatusCode == 405)
        {
            Response.RedirectToRoute("Controller/ResolverError");
        }
    }
```

Getting **Response** from the HTTP context, checking the status code, and then redirecting the request to the specific controller.